# How to debug the error "'fout' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

I need to make the following:

> is considered a chessboard of size nxn they are willing obstacles. Required to print the minimum number of moves required to move a madman, respecting the rules of chess and avoiding obstacles, from an initial position to a final position on time. It is believed that the initial and final position of the fool there are no obstacles.

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define INF 9999

int a[100][100];
int c[100][100];
int ip, jp, is, js;
int i,j;
int m, n;
const int di[] = { -1, 0, 1, 0 },
    dj[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };

bool OK( int i, int j );
void Lee();
void Write();
void Read();

int main()
 {
    Read();
    Lee();
    Write();

    return 0;
     }

  void Read()
    {
    ifstream fin("lee.in");
    fin >> n >> m;
    fin >> ip >> jp >> is >> js;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ )
            {
                    fin >> a[i][j];
                    c[i][j] = INF;
            }
    fin.close();
      }

      bool OK()
       {
      if ( a[i][j] == 1 ){ return false;} // obstacol, marcat de cifra 1 aici.
    if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= n || j >= m ){}
            return false; // in afara matricei
    return true;  // niciuna din conditiile de mai sus nu au fost adevarate.
             }

    void Lee()
       {
    c[ip][jp] = 0; // punctul de plecare. distanta pana la el fiind de 0.
    bool modif;
    int pas = 0; // numarul de pasi efectuati.
    do
    {
            modif = false;
            for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
                            for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ )
                                    if ( c[i][j] == pas ) 
                              for ( int d = 0; d < 4; ++d )
                                            {

                                                    int iv = i + di[d];
                                                    int jv = j + dj[d];
                                                    if ( OK( iv, jv) )
                                                    {
                  c[iv][jv] = pas + 1;
                                                            modif = true;
          if ( iv == is && jv == js ) 
                                                                    return;
                                                    }
                                            }
                   pas++;
            } while ( modif );
              }

                void Write()
                  {
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
            for ( int j = 0; j < m; j++ )
                            fout << c[i][j] << ' ';
            fout << '\n';
    }
    fout >> c[is][js];


            }
```

I have 3 errors "'fout' was not declared in this scope", I don't know which is the cause.

Comment: And you declared `fout` where exactly? I can't spot it.

Comment: Your indentation makes it very difficult to read the code.

Comment: i need to declare fout ? the fout code is in the end of code

Comment: @BrasoveanNicolae _"i need to declare fout ?"_ Sure, same way as you already did with `fin` correctly, using `std::ofstream` of course.

Comment: There should be a close option for *seriously bad formatting*. How is anyone expected to read that code?

Comment: I don't understand how someone can look at code this poorly formatted and literally think "okay great I'm going to put this on the internet for other people to read now". How does that happen?!

Answer (score 3):

Declare fout using `ofstream fout(filename);` at an appropriate place in the code.

Comment: so i declared and i have other error " no match for 'operator>>' in 'fout >> c[is][js]'" at the end of code ...

Comment: Operator `>>` is for input streams. You have a declaration of an `ifstream fin("lee.in")`. To do more `ifstream()` operations declare another such that `fin1 >> c[is][js]`. Or is it a bug and you wanted to do `<<`?

Comment: using fout >> are you trying to extract input?
if so change ofstream to fstream or use ifstream

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= n || j >= m ){}
     return false; // in afara matricei
return true;  // niciuna din conditiile de mai sus nu au fost adevarate.
```

The `if` executes `{}` when the condition is true, so `return false` will *always* be executed.

Remove the braces at the end of the `if`.

Comment: @BrasoveanNicolae: Stop. You're treating this place like a chatroom, or a customer support desk. We're not here to fix all your errors one by one, one after another. Take more than two minutes on a problem before giving up and expecting us to do it for free. Spend some time _studying_ and _learning_ because these are basics. Perform some _research_ before asking.

Comment: @BrasoveanNicolae SO can help solving _one_ specific issue. Your code has many, and clearly shows that you are not yet understanding enough C++ to solve the task at hand. You should postpone writing this program, and start reading some C++ tutorial/book, learn C++, solve simpler exercises, and come back at this after you are more fluent with the language.